# Sorting a list, storing in localStorage and displaying in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on an iOS web app. There is a list view of accounts that I would like to be able to let the user sort however they'd like. Right now, the sorting function works — the user can tap "edit" and grab an item and rearrange it. I was able to save the user's rearranged order in an array by giving each list item a "data-id" of a number, but when you refresh the page, it goes back to default.

Below is a portion of my code. If you want to see the web app in it's entirety, [here's a link to my website](http://www.jordankennedy.com/balancepro/index.html).

```js
function showAccountsArray() {

  if (localStorage.getItem("accountsArray") === null) {
    document.getElementById("getStarted").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("balanceToolbarName").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("accountsMainList").style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {

    var accountsLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage['accountsArray']);
    console.log(accountsLocalStorage);

    var accountInfo = '';
    var i = 0;
    while (i < accountsLocalStorage.length) {
      accountInfo += '<li class="swipeout" data-id=\"' + i + '\"><a href="#" class="item-link"><div class="swipeout-content item-content"><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title">' + accountsLocalStorage[i].accountName + '</div><div class="item-after">$' + accountsLocalStorage[i].accountBalance + '</div></div></div><div class="swipeout-actions-left"><a href="#" class="action1">Clear</a></div><div class="swipeout-actions-right"><a href="#" class="action1">Delete</a></div><div class="sortable-handler"></div></a></li>';
      document.getElementById("accountsList").innerHTML = accountInfo;
      i++;
    }

    document.getElementById("getStarted").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("balanceToolbarName").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("accountsMainList").style.visibility = "visible";

  }

}


// Saves accounts to local storage
$(function() {
  var data = localStorage.getItem("accountsArray");

  if (data != null)
    accountsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("accountsArray"));
});


// Sort the order of accounts
var accountsSortedList = [];
$('.list-block.sortable').on('sort', function() {
  $(this).find('li').each(function() {
    accountsSortedList.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
    console.log(accountsSortedList);
    localStorage.setItem('accountsSortedList', JSON.stringify(accountsSortedList));
  });
})
```

Comment: can you simply save the list's .html() and set it back onready(), or does it get all yucky with dynamic attributes?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the item ID you're pulling from localStorage is different from the one you're setting. You have to change one or the other so that they both match and that should solve your problem, ie. set "accountsSortedList" to "accountArray" or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to a different storage item than you are reading.  You store the sorted value in `localStorage` as `accountsSortedList`, but then you never read that value.  Since you are loading from `accountsArray`, you should also write the sorted values there.

```
localStorage.setItem('accountsArray', JSON.stringify(accountsSortedList));
```

Also, you are writing to `localStorage` in a loop, overwriting the value each time.  The result you end up with is ultimately correct, but really you should move the call to set the `localStorage` value to be outside of the loop.

```
$('.list-block.sortable').on('sort', function() {
  var accountsSortedList = $(this).find('li').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('id');
  });
  localStorage.setItem('accountsArray', JSON.stringify(accountsSortedList));
});
```

---

By the way, you don't have to use the `getItem()` and `setItem()` methods.  Personally, I prefer dot syntax:

```
var accountsLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.accountsArray);
...
localStorage.accountsArray = accountsSortedList;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am new to programming, so I apologize for the ignorance. I guess I'm confused on how I read that `accountsSortedList` out of the saved `localStorage`. I moved the storing to outside the loop, and that makes sense. Would I need to load the array into the while loop where it outputs the HTML?

Comment: @jryankennedy - Currently you are reading `localStorage.accountsArray` but writing `localStorage.accountsSortedList`.  You should read what you write.  Change your code to write the sorted array to `localStorage.accountsArray`.  That way, when you read it, you are reading the sorted values.